# Django logging features?

Tags: python, django

I need to run a lot of Django management commands in the crontab and want to log the output of each run to a special timestamped file.  Is there a Django or Python module to help me do this or do I just have to roll my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [django-jogging](http://github.com/zain/jogging). It's a breeze to set up all kinds of custom logging with it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Python logging package which is part of Python, see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598823/elegant-setup-of-python-logging-in-django/1598979#1598979) to another question about elegant setup of logging in Django. You can inspect `sys.argv` to determine how you want to do logging, e.g. redirect to different files for different commands.

Answer (score 1):

as of django 1.3 a better logging configuration approach is available. please check my answer to.. the same question pointed at by Vinay :-)

[Elegant setup of Python logging in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598823/elegant-setup-of-python-logging-in-django/5806903#5806903)