# How do I configure the Python logging module in Django?

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm trying to configure logging for a Django app using the Python `logging` module. I have placed the following bit of configuration code in my Django project's `settings.py` file:

```
import logging
import logging.handlers
import os
date_fmt = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S'
log_formatter = logging.Formatter(u'[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)-7s: %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)d)', datefmt=date_fmt)
log_dir = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "var", "log", "my_app")
log_name = os.path.join(log_dir, "nyrb.log")
bytes = 1024 * 1024   # 1 MB
if not os.path.exists(log_dir):
  os.makedirs(log_dir)
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(log_name, maxBytes=bytes, backupCount=7)
handler.setFormatter(log_formatter)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)
logging.getLogger(__name__).info("Initialized logging subsystem")
```

At startup, I get a couple Django-related messages, as well as the "Initialized logging subsystem", in the log files, but then all the log messages end up going to the web server logs (`/var/log/apache2/error.log`, since I'm using Apache), and use the standard log format (not the formatter I designated). Am I configuring logging incorrectly?

Comment: What if you will remove last line? So that logging system will stay not touched until the process forks. Just a thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of anti-climactic, but it turns out there was a third-party app installed in the project that had its own logging configuration that was overriding the one I set up (it modified the root logger, for some reason -- not very kosher for a Django app!). Removed that code and everything works as expected.

Comment: I have been trying to figure out a logging issue and this finally pointed me in the right direction - I never though about a 3rd party app overriding the root logger. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I used this with success (although it does not *rotate*):

```
# in settings.py
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level = logging.DEBUG,
    format = '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(funcName)s %(lineno)d \
              \033[35m%(message)s\033[0m', 
    datefmt = '[%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S]',
    filename = '/tmp/my_django_app.log',
    filemode = 'a'
)
```

I'd suggest to try an absolute path, too.

Answer (score 2):

See [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598823/elegant-setup-of-python-logging-in-django). Note that settings.py is usually imported twice, so you should avoid creating multiple handlers. Better logging support is coming to Django in 1.3 (hopefully), but for now you should ensure that if your setup code is called more than once, there are no adverse effects.

I'm not sure why your logged messages are going to the Apache logs, unless you've (somewhere else in your code) added a StreamHandler to your root logger with `sys.stdout` or `sys.stderr` as the stream. You might want to print out `logging.getLogger().handlers` just to see it's what you'd expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

I guess logging stops when Apache forks the process. After that happened, because all file descriptors were closed during daemonization, logging system tries to reopen log file and as far as I understand uses *relative* file path:

```
log_dir = os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR, "var", "log", "my_app")
log_name = os.path.join(log_dir, "nyrb.log")
```

But there is no “current directory” when process has been daemonized. Try to use absolute `log_dir` path. Hope that helps.