# How do I write to the apache log files when using mod_wsgi

Tags: python, apache, logging, mod-wsgi

I have a Django project where I have been logging to a file using the standard library logging module.  For a variety of reasons I would like to change it so that it writes to the Apache log files.  I've seen quite a bit of discussion of how to do this with mod_python, but not mod_wsgi.  How do I do this for a project running under mod_wsgi?

Comment: Step 1.  Search.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdjango%5D+apache+log  Step 2. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598823/elegant-setup-of-python-logging-in-django

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Mostly, we use logging and write to `sys.stderr`.  That seems to write to the Apache error_log.

Comment: Thanks.  That seems to be the way to do it.  The comments on this post http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1731/ say the same thing.

Comment: As simple as that. Great!!

Comment: @DavidMontgomery:  the comment you link to is helpful.  A currently more legible version of the same comment can be found at http://artyname.tumblr.com/post/390511693/log-django-exceptions-to-apache-error-log-in