# Using a separate email account for error emails in Django

Tags: python, django

What's the easiest way to configure Django to send error emails to a special email account?

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/error-reporting/#email-reports) on error emails don't explicitly mention any way to do this. I know how to write a custom [email backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#topic-email-backends) that could lookup and use different credentials, but as the EmailBackend._send method only receives the message, I'm not sure how to detect when the message is in response to a 500 server error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use the logging settings to mail 500 errors to the admin email ids.

Example of a logging setup :

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        }
    }
}
```

This will mail all 500 errors in django to the mentioned email ids.

See:
[Elegant setup of Python logging in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598823/elegant-setup-of-python-logging-in-django)

and :

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#an-example

If you want to use another SMTP server, then use exception middleware .

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/#process-exception

in the `process_exception` method, you can email the traceback of exception to required
email accounts.

Comment: I'm not trying to just send 500 errors to a specific email address. That's clearly documented. I want to use completely different email account credentials entirely. I don't want error emails going through the same SMTP server used for normal emails.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19001979/483642 It is way easy than below answer. You just need inherit `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend` and set `email_backend` on your logging config.