# Django - Using a different email backend for admin error emails

Tags: python, django, logging, django-settings, django-email

I'm using a custom email backend in my Django application (CeleryEmailBackend in this case):

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'djcelery_email.backends.CeleryEmailBackend'
```

My logging configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
    # ...
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
    },
    # ...
}
```

The Admin error emails also get sent by the same email backend.
So if there is a problem with the email backend (e.g. Celery is not running). Then I won't receive the server error emails.

Is there a way to make `AdminEmailHandler` use a custom email backend?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible, but in django 1.6, quote from [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler):

> By setting the email_backend argument of AdminEmailHandler, the email
>   backend that is being used by the handler can be overridden, like
>   this:

```
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler',
        'email_backend': 'django.core.mail.backends.filebased.EmailBackend',
    }
},
```

If you don't want to upgrade (since 1.6 is not stable, for example), consider making a custom email handler based on [AdminEmailHandler](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ad6fcdb8d24d84a130f847f45b51d7e892ccca08/django/utils/log.py#L65). Should not be hard, because the actual implementation of this [new feature](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/19325) is pretty straight-forward and clean (see [pull-request](https://github.com/django/django/pull/546/files)).

Or, you can actually extract the whole `AdminEmailHandler` class from the django 1.6 and use it as a custom email handler.

Comment: Found it just now... Is there a some kind of workaround for 1.5?

Comment: For some reason, this solution does'nt work for 1.8 for me. Any one with a similar issue??