# How to see details of Django errors with Gunicorn?

Tags: django, bash, nginx, gunicorn, django-errors

I just deployed my Django (1.6) project with gunicorn and Nginx.

It seems to be working fine but I have one page were I'm getting an HTTP 500 error and I can't find any details about the error anywhere.

How do I get gunicorn to show me errors?

Here's all I currently see in the log file when I hit the page giving me the error:

```
>tail gunicorn.errors 
2014-02-21 14:41:02 [22676] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/opt/djangoprojects/reports/bin/gunicorn.sock (22676)
2014-02-21 14:41:02 [22676] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-02-21 14:41:02 [22689] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 22689
...
2014-02-21 19:41:10 [22691] [DEBUG] GET /reports/2/
```

Here's my bash script I use to start gunicorn:

```
>cat gunicorn_start
#!/bin/bash

NAME="reports"                                  # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/opt/djangoprojects/reports          # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/opt/djangoprojects/reports/bin/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=reportsuser                                        # the user to run as
GROUP=webapps                                     # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=4                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=reports.settings             # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=reports.wsgi                     # WSGI module name

#echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source pythonenv/bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --log-level=debug \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --error-logfile /opt/djangoprojects/reports/bin/gunicorn.errors \
  --log-file /opt/djangoprojects/reports/bin/gunicorn.errors
```

More info:

I'm starting/stopping gunicorn with this init.d script I copied and modified using `sudo service reports start|stop|restart`:

```
>cat /etc/init.d/reports
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          django_gunicorn
# Required-Start:    $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs $network $remote_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Starts django_unicorn reports at boot time.
# Description:       Starts django_unicorn reports at boot time.
### END INIT INFO

name=`basename $0`
dir="/opt/djangoprojects/reports"
cmd="${dir}/bin/gunicorn_start"
pid_file="/var/run/$name.pid"
log_file="${dir}/bin/reports.log"

get_pid() {
    cat "$pid_file"    
}

is_running() {
    [ -f "$pid_file" ] && ps `get_pid` > /dev/null 2>&1
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    if is_running; then
        echo "Already running"
    else
        echo -n "Starting ${name}... "
        cd "$dir"
        #sudo -u "$user" $cmd &>> "$log_file"
        $cmd &>> "$log_file" &
        echo $! > "$pid_file"
        if ! is_running; then
            echo "Unable to start; see $log_file"
            exit 1
        else
            echo "[STARTED]"
        fi
    fi
    ;;
    stop)
    if is_running; then
        echo -n "Stopping ${name}... "
        kill `get_pid`
        for i in {1..10}
        do
            if ! is_running; then
                break
            fi

            echo -n "."
            sleep 1
        done
        echo

        if is_running; then
            echo "Not stopped; may still be shutting down or shutdown may have failed"
            exit 1
        else
            echo "[STOPPED]"
            if [ -f "$pid_file" ]; then
                rm "$pid_file"
            fi
        fi
    else
        echo "Not running"
    fi
    ;;
    restart)
    $0 stop
    if is_running; then
        echo "Unable to stop, will not attempt to start"
        exit 1
    fi
    $0 start
    ;;
    status)
    if is_running; then
        echo "[RUNNING]"
    else
        echo "[STOPPED]"
        exit 1
    fi
    ;;
    *)
    echo "Usage: $0 {start|stop|restart|status}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac

exit 0
```

Comment: Set django setting `DEBUG` to True, and reload it, it should display more detail of the error

Comment: Ok, I tried that, and I do see the error on the page which helps.  But I'm looking for a more general solution, and this is a production environment so I can't really leave debug=True on.  It doesn't seem to help with showing errors in the gunicorn log file either.

Answer (score 31):

From your comment I think this is a config problem in your django site, not a matter of gunicorn log, logs will not show more than django send to it.

Here is an example of how you can configure django setting to send log to your file (instead of send it to admins by email as default):

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': True,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format': '%(asctime)s %(levelname)s [%(name)s:%(lineno)s] %(module)s %(process)d %(thread)d %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'gunicorn': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose',
            'filename': '/opt/djangoprojects/reports/bin/gunicorn.errors',
            'maxBytes': 1024 * 1024 * 100,  # 100 mb
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'gunicorn.errors': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'handlers': ['gunicorn'],
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Read [configuring logging](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#configuring-logging) (it provide a very well explanations of log settings options) and study the file [django/utils/log.py](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/utils/log.py) to configure django loggin to appears more detailed on gunicorn logs.

Also check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5806903/2343488) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6395837/2343488) which provide setting examples to send logs errors directly to a file. And consider to use [Sentry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sentry) to handle log errors, as is [recomended](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#id3) by django guys.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh, so you're saying newer versions of Django simply don't log errors by default?  I'd been seeing tracebacks when running the built in Django server so I assumed I'd get the same output when running through Gunicorn.

Comment: By default ERROR and CRITICAL level are sent by email to admin, I think built in Django dev server not use this function, so it show tracebacks in the console

Answer (score 28):

This configuration worked for me. Add `--capture-output --enable-stdio-inheritance` with gunicorn command like below.

```
/home/ubuntu/inside-env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile /var/log/access_file_g.log --error-logfile /var/log/error_file_g.log --capture-output --enable-stdio-inheritance --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/ubuntu/path-to-project/webapp.sock project.wsgi:application
```

With this setup, do enable logging in this way

```
import logging 
logging.basicConfig(level='DEBUG')

logging.info('hello world')
```

This way you will get to see the errors in the App as well.

Comment: Underrated answer, this is what I was looking for so many times. Thanks !

Comment: Thanks a lot, man. This worked out perfectly for me.

Comment: 10 years later!!

Answer (score 15):

#### Short answer:

With following logging configuration, your errors will start showing up in Gunicorn output(undaemonized) or runserver even when DEBUG is False. They anyways should be showing up when DEBUG is True.

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
    },
    'require_debug_true': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
    },
},
'formatters': {
    'django.server': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.ServerFormatter',
        'format': '[%(server_time)s] %(message)s',
    }
},
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
    },
    # Custom handler which we will use with logger 'django'.
    # We want errors/warnings to be logged when DEBUG=False
    'console_on_not_debug': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
    },
    'django.server': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        'formatter': 'django.server',
    },
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins', 'console_on_not_debug'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
    'django.server': {
        'handlers': ['django.server'],
        'level': 'INFO',
        'propagate': False,
    },
}
}
```

If you want to see the Django errors in gunicorn error log, run gunicorn with --capture-output.

http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#capture-output

#### Long answer

There are two confusions involved when logging:

1. Whether `runserver` provide better log than `gunicorn`
2. Does `settings.DEBUG=True` provide better log than `settings.DEBUG=False`

**Any** log record you see with runserver can be seen with Gunicorn too as long as you have appropriate logging configuration.

**Any** log record you see with DEBUG=True can be seen while DEBUG=False too as long as you have appropriate logging configuration.

You can see default Django logging configuration at:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.8/django/utils/log.py#L18

It looks like: (I have stripped out parts which don't concern this answer)

```
DEFAULT_LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'filters': {
    'require_debug_false': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse',
    },
    'require_debug_true': {
        '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugTrue',
    },
},
'handlers': {
    'console': {
        'level': 'INFO',
        'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
    },
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
},
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
}
}
```

What this says is:

1. Send `django` logger log record to handlers `console` and `mail_admins`.
2. Handler `console` has a filter `require_debug_true` on it. When settings.DEBUG is True, then handler `console` sends/prints the log on the Stream (because of `logging.StreamHandler`).

When settings.DEBUG is False, then handler `console` ignores the log message sent to it by logger `django`.

If you want logs to be printed with DEBUG=False too, then add a `handler` and make logger `django` use it.

Handler would look like:

```
    'console_on_not_debug': {
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
        'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
    },
```

And use this handler with logger `django`:

```
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'mail_admins', 'console_on_not_debug'],
        'level': 'INFO',
    },
```

You can see the entire snippet in short answer.

With this, the logs will be printed on stream irrespective of if you are using runserver or gunicorn.

If you want the logs to be shown in gunicorn error log, then you need to run gunicorn with --capture-output.

Comment: fantastic answer, even the ai couldn't solve this for me. thanks, still valid many years later!

Answer (score 7):

## 1. sending errors to the console

These are the `loggers` that use `mail_admins` by default (see `django/utils/log.py`):

```
    'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': False,
    },
    'django.security': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'propagate': False,
    },
```

you would need to change the handlers to go to the `console` so that it appears in your gunicorn log rather than send emails with `mail_admins`. Please note that it's not as chatty as when `DEBUG=True`.

```
 'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'handlers': ['console'],
    },
 }
```

## 2. sending errors via `mail_admins`

Also based on configuring logging, explicitly create a handler that calls `mail_admins`; e.g. based on `django/utils/log.py`:

```
 'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    },
 },
 'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
    },
 }
```

This requires you to set email related `settings`.

## 3. other solutions

If you were not looking for solution #1, then your question is a duplicate of:
[How do you log server errors on django sites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238081/how-do-you-log-server-errors-on-django-sites)

Answer (score 5):

Running Django 3.8 on Heroku with gunicorn 20.1, I had the problem that application errors were not showing up in the Papertrail logs.

To fix this all I had to do was add the [minimal recommended logging configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/#examples) from the Django docs to settings.py:

```py
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'WARNING',
    },
}
```

This is necessary because in [Django's default logging configuration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/logging/#django-s-default-logging-configuration) in production (when `DEBUG` is `False`) the django logger sends messages to `AdminEmailHandler`, instead of to the console.

I am starting gunicorn in the Procfile with `web: gunicorn my_project.wsgi`, and I did not need to change that (i.e. I did not need to use `--capture-output` or `--enable-stdio-inheritance`).

Comment: This is the proper answer for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution is to configure the variable **[ADMINS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#admins)** with email addresses of people who should get error notifications.
When DEBUG=False and a view raises an exception, Django will email these people with the full exception information.

settings.py

```
ADMINS = (('John', 'john@example.com'), ('Mary', 'mary@example.com'))
# or only ADMINS = (('John', 'john@example.com'),)
```

Maybe you need also EMAIL_HOST and EMAIL_PORT if the right SMTP server is not `localhost` on port `25`. This simple solution is good enough for trial production operation, otherwise it can produce suddenly too much emails.