# How to log information of a docker container

Tags: logging, amazon-ec2, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose.yml file that has 3 services
1) nginx : reverse-proxy
2) web   : a simple application that takes performs classification using ridge classifier
3) viz   : presents statistics of docker information, like CPU used, number of containers used

Below is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    restart: always
    build: ./web
    expose:
      - "8000"
    volumes:
      - ./output:/usr/src/app/static
    command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 -b :8000 --access-logfile - classifierv2RestEndPoint_ridge_NB:create_app()

  nginx:
    restart: always
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /www/static
    volumes_from:
      - web
    links:
      - web:web

  viz:
    image: dockersamples/visualizer
    ports:
      - 8080:8080/tcp
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
      - "constraint=node.role==manager"
```

In 'web' service I have a simple UI that takes a an excel file as input and upon clicking submit button it outputs the result of classifier.

[image]
if I incorrectly select a wrong file and click submit it throws an error

[image]

However when I check the docker-compose logs, I do not see why the error is happening. I see this

[image]

I want to see where in the program is the error happening but not HTTP POST request log

```
web_1    | 172.19.0.4 - - [10/Sep/2017:17:41:07 +0000] "POST / HTTP/1.0" 500 291 "http                                                          ://ec2-35-154-66-136.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;                                                           Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36
```

What should I do to see the error in my classifier code?

```
                                                  "
```

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21943962/how-to-see-details-of-django-errors-with-gunicorn

Comment: Thank you yes it helped, I was using a Flask application in 'web' service. I set app.debug = True and now I can see the errors.

Comment: Why is the error coming? Do post your findings