# Customize logging for external/third-party libs

Tags: python, django, logging

I followed the advice of the django docs, and use logging like this:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def today(...):
    logger.info('Sun is shining, the weather is sweet')
```

With my current configuration, the output looks like this:

```
2016-08-11 14:54:06 mylib.foo.today: INFO Sun is shining, the weather is sweet
```

Unfortunately some libraries which I can't modify use logging like this:

```
import logging

def third_party(...):
    logging.info('Make you want to move your dancing feet')
```

The output unfortunately looks like this:

```
2016-08-09 08:28:04 root.third_party: INFO Make you want to move your dancing feet
```

I want to see this:

```
2016-08-09 08:28:04 other_lib.some_file.third_party: INFO Make you want to move your dancing feet
```

Difference:

*root.third_party* ==> *other_lib.some_file.third_party*

I want to see the long version (not `root`) if code uses `logging.info()` instead of `logger.info()`

**Update**

This is not a duplicate of [Elegant setup of Python logging in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598823/elegant-setup-of-python-logging-in-django), since the solution of it is:

Start of quote

In each module, I define a logger using

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

End of quote.

No, I won't modify third-party-code which uses `logging.info()` instead of `logger.info()`.

**Follow Up Question**

[Avoid `logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)` without loosing way to filter logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38952681/)

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/logging/ you should configure it in your settings.py

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elegant setup of Python logging in Django](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1598823/elegant-setup-of-python-logging-in-django)

Comment: @be_good_do_good yes, I configured logging. The question is: How to handle loggers which are not named with `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

Comment: Also, I'd probably file a bug report with the upstream library. There's no excuse for *not* using `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` in a module.

Comment: Could you partially solve this issues by logging file name? File name should respect PYTHONPATH, therefore should be unique. It is not logger name, but should be pretty close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Wayne Werner suggested, I would use the Log Record format options. Here's an example.

File 1: `external_module`

```
import logging
def third_party():
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    logger = logging.getLogger()

    logger.info("Hello from %s!"%__name__)
```

File 2: `main`

```
import external_module
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG,
                    format='%(asctime)s %(module)s.%(funcName)s: %(levelname)s %(message)s')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def cmd():
    logger.info("Hello from %s!"%__name__)
    external_module.third_party()
cmd()
```

Output:

```
2016-08-11 09:18:17,993 main.cmd: INFO Hello from __main__!
2016-08-11 09:18:17,993 external_module.third_party(): INFO Hello from external_module!
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because they're using the root logger (which is what you get by default when you just do

```
import logging

logging.info("Hi! I'm the root logger!")
```

If you want to do something different you have two (or three) options. The best would be to use the [Log Record format options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes). Alternatively, you could monkey patch the libraries that you're using, e.g.

```
import logging
import mod_with_lazy_logging

mod_with_lazy_logging.logger = logging.getLogger(mod_with_lazy_logging.__name__)
```

Or you could do something gnarly with parsing the ast and rewriting their bits of logging code. But, don't do that.

Comment: Monkey Patching the library could work. But it has a lot of files ... It feels like too much work.

Comment: If it's an open source library, I'd recommend either filing an issue with the maintainer, or creating a PR yourself. Or both. Not using `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`, or at least using `'library name'` seems lazy/irresponsible.