# Avoid `logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)` without loosing way to filter logs

Tags: python, logging

I am lazy and want to avoid this line in every python file which uses logging:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

In january I asked how this could be done, and found an answer: [Avoid `logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34726515/avoid-logger-logging-getlogger-name)

Unfortunately the answer there has the drawback, that you loose the ability to filter.

I really want to avoid this useless and redundant line.

Example:

```
import logging

def my_method(foo):
    logging.info()
```

Unfortunately I think it is impossible do `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` implicitly if `logging.info()` gets called for the first time in this file.

Is there anybody out there who knows how to do impossible stuff?

**Update**

I like [Don't Repeat Yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself). If most files contain the same line at the top, I think this is a repetition. It looks like [WET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself#DRY_vs_WET_solutions). The python interpreter in my head needs to skip this line every time I look there. My subjective feeling: this line is useless bloat. The line should be the implicit default.

Comment: Is it really *that hard* to define that *one line* at the top of your module? You already had to type out `import logging`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't type "import logging". I have an IDE which does this. I type "logging.[MAGIC-KEY-STROKE]" in the method and the IDE inserts the import statement at the top. Yes, I don't want to type this line. It's bloat. I want less code, not more.

Comment: It is not bloat; it is an explicit declaration that you want a logger object with that name. In a package you could reuse that logger for all submodules if you don't care about the name. You can easily use  different hierarchy of names. Moreover, anything else would require a custom module subclass with a custom `__getattr__` that then checks the call frame for a `__name__` key in the globals to produce the same object. Python prefers being explicit over such magic.

Comment: If you are using an IDE, then perhaps it could be something the IDE does for you. Perhaps it has auto-expanding snippet support? You type `logger<TAB>` and the import and the `getLogger(__name__)` call are inserted for you? This is not something Python has to solve for you.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you said "It is not bloat". I updated the question. See "Update". But I think this paragraph I added did not add anything substantial.

Answer (score 2):

Think well if you really want to do this.

Create a Module e.g. `magiclog.py` like this:

```
import logging
import inspect

def L():
    # FIXME: catch indexing errors
    callerframe = inspect.stack()[1][0]
    name = callerframe.f_globals["__name__"]
    # avoid cyclic ref, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack
    del callerframe
    return logging.getLogger(name)
```

Then you can do:

```
from magiclog import L
L().info("it works!")
```

Comment: Cool, this looks like the first step. Now this should be executed if I do `import logging` and `logging.info("it works!")`

Comment: Well you can of course monkeypatch the functions in the logging module, but then you're really crossing the line into "evil" territory. (i.e. anybody inheriting your code will have a fun time).

Answer (score 1):

> I am lazy and want to avoid this line in every python file which uses
>   logging:
>
> ```
> logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
> ```

Well, it's the recommended way:

> A good convention to use when naming loggers is to use a module-level
>   logger, in each module which uses logging, named as follows:
>
> ```
> logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
> ```
>
> This means that logger names track the package/module hierarchy, and
>   it’s intuitively obvious where events are logged just from the logger
>   name.

That's a quote from the official [howto](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html#advanced-logging-tutorial).

> I like Don't Repeat Yourself. If most files contain the same line at
>   the top, I think this is a repetition. It looks like WET. The python
>   interpreter in my head needs to skip this line every time I look
>   there. My subjective feeling: this line is useless bloat. The line
>   should be the implicit default.

It follows "Explicit is better than implicit". Anyway you can easily change a python template in many IDEs to always include this line or make a new template file.

Comment: And now to something completely different, but don't take it too serious: Ironing socks was the recommend way several years ago. Every good housewife did it. Most people stopped doing this none sense.

Comment: I got 99 programming problems but explicit one-liner for logging setup ain't one. That's my nonserious reply.